# h5py: How to abstract indices

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, h5py

I have an HDF5 file with subgroups that I currently index like:

```
file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
data = np.array(file[index1][index2][index3])
```

I would rather abstract those indices and pass a list instead (`indices = [index1, index2, index3]`) but I can't think of a more efficient way to implement it than:

```
indices = [index1, index2, index3]
file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
data = file
for i in indices:
     data = data[i]
data = np.array(data)
```

This works, but I was hoping there was a one-liner for this problem.

Comment: What kind of object is ```file```? If it is a numpy array i reckon it should be as easy as doing: ```data = file[tuple(indices)]```.

Comment: `file` is an HDF5 file object: https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do.

- Are `index1, index2, and index3` all datasets at the root level (aka
  the file group, so you have `/index1`, `/index2`, and `/index3`).
- Or is `index1` a group, `index2` a subgroup, and `index3` is a
  dataset? (so the path is `/index1/index2/index3`?)

If they are all datasets, this will loop thru the indices and return an array each time.

```
indices = [index1, index2, index3]
file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
for i in indices:
    arr = file[i][:] # returns a np.array, one per loop
```

If indices define a path to a dataset, this returns 1 array.

```
indices = [index1, index2, index3]
file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
path = '/'+'/'.join(indices)
arr = file[path][:] # returns 1 np.array
```

Comment: Yes, my indices form a path to a dataset, so the latter is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `h5py` explain how to index groups and datasets well enough?

The `file` and groups are modeled Python `dict`, where you select the next level with a keyword.  `file['group1']['group2']['dataset1']`.  A dataset can be indexed like an array, or can be loaded as a whole with `[:]`.

Names can be strung together, e.g.

```
file['group1/group2/dataset1'][:]
```

While I haven't tested this, I don't think there's any "efficiency" difference.  As with `dicts` nothing (much) is loaded until you load a dataset.

By the way, a "one liner" is not "efficient" by any measure (except if you are counting lines :)  ).

Comment: In this case, I am counting lines. Maybe I should have been more pedantic with my use of efficient. Thank you! I didn't realize names could be strung together, and that helps.